# How to display a popup message after completing the Ajax.actionlink call in myasp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have the following ajax.actionlink:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
              OnSuccess = "removePartial2",
          })
```

**currently if the call was successful it will call the removePartial2 java script,,, but how i can display a confirmation message after successfully completing the call that the "Deletion was successful"???**

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in the `removePartial2` function:

```
function removePartial2(result) {
    alert('Deletion was successful');
}
```

Comment: i tried this , it works well on internet explorer but it did not work on firefox ,,,